# Clear screen in python without external modules

Tags: python, windows, cls

As in the title, im using windows cmd. 
I know there is:

```
print("\n" * rows)
```

but it leaves cursor at the bottom of the terminal. Is there any way to clear screen when not leaving the cursor at the botom while using no modules?

Comment: Easiest would be `system('cls')` but you still need to import `os` for that. Why the requirement of not using modules?

Comment: @CherryDT It doesn't matter, i just can't.

Comment: Well it sort of matters because this sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @CherryDT It has nothing to do with code, it's just my goal to write a specified program without using any modules.

Comment: At startup `os` should already be loaded in `sys.modules`, so you're aren't  avoiding the actual import by avoiding `import os`. Moreover, most of os is defined in the builtin module `nt` on Windows or `posix` in Unix, e.g. `os.system` is actually `nt.system`.